# question: A jar on your desk contains twelve black, nine red,

Tags: probability

1-A jar on your desk contains 12 black, 9 red, 9 yellow, and 5 green jellybeans. You pick a jellybean without looking.

Find the odds of picking a black jellybean.

my Answer 12/35

2-A jar on your desk contains 12 black, 13 red, 9 yellow, and 6 green jellybeans. You pick a jellybean without looking.

(a)Find the odds of picking a red or black jellybean.

my Answer 25/40

3- One card is drawn from a well-shuffled deck of 52 cards (no jokers).

(a) Find the odds of drawing a red card.

my Answer 26/52

4-One card is drawn from a well-shuffled deck of 52 cards (no jokers).

(a) Find the odds of drawing a 10 of spades.

my Answer 1/52

but it's considered all my answers wrong  :(

I don't know where is the mistake , any help please

Answer (score 3):

The key is they want "odds" not "probability".

"Probability" is favourable divided by total, so $12/35$ would have been right for the first question, if that was what the wanted.   But it wasn't.

"Odds" is favourable versus unfavourable, so they wanted odds of $12:23$ for the first question.

Comment: how you got 19, I think there is only 12 black not 19